# Find the closest value in the group for each value in the group R

Tags: r, dataframe

It's been two days since I'm trying to find this :

I have a dataframe with more than 2 mil observations with this structure

```
id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
sex = c('M','F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F')
time = c(10, 11, 11.5, 13, 13.2, 15, 9, 7.4, 18, 12, 34.5, 21)
```

I would like to find for each female the male with the closest time and this by group

By example here id = 2 is a female in the group 1 with time = 11 the closest male in the group 1 is id = 3

ect for each female in each group

I tried to use something like this

```
keep <- function(x){
   a <-  df[which.min(abs(df[which(df[,'sex'] == "M"),'time']-x[,'time'])),]
   return(a) 
}

apply(df, 1, keep)
```

But it does not work.

If someone can help me it would be great.

Comment: The numbers of males and females isn't the same, so directly subtracting the times for each group with a vectorized a - b calculation won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after something like below?

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  c(
    .SD[sex == "F"],
    .(closestM_id = id[sex == "M"][max.col(-abs(outer(
      time[sex == "F"],
      time[sex == "M"], "-"
    )))])
  ), group
]
```

which gives

```
   group id sex time closestM_id
1:     1  2   F 11.0           3
2:     2  6   F 15.0           5
3:     2  7   F  9.0           5
4:     2  8   F  7.4           5
5:     3 12   F 21.0           9
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12),
    group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), sex = c("M",
    "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F"), time = c(10,
    11, 11.5, 13, 13.2, 15, 9, 7.4, 18, 12, 34.5, 21)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-12L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm trrying to make it work with my full data.frame

Comment: When I'm trying it return NA for all closestM_id. I think it's because my group variable is a 'factor' with letter an not a list of integer

Comment: It works perfectly find, thank you very much ! Forget about my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution using a rolling join to nearest time.
Using the `df` from Thomas' answer

```
setDT(df)
df[sex=="F",][,closestM_id := df[sex=="M",][df[sex=="F",], 
                                            x.id, 
                                            on = .(group, time), roll = "nearest"]]
#    id group sex time closestM_id
# 1:  2     1   F 11.0           3
# 2:  6     2   F 15.0           5
# 3:  7     2   F  9.0           5
# 4:  8     2   F  7.4           5
# 5: 12     3   F 21.0           9
```

Comment: great answer with `roll =` option

Answer (score 0):

You could split the `data.frame()` into groups of males and females then use `outer()` to find the absolute difference in time of all combinations.

**Code:**

```
lapply(split(df, df[, "group"]), function(x){
  # split by sex
  tmp1 <- split(x, x[, "sex"])
  
  # time difference for every combination
  tmp2 <- abs(t(outer(tmp1[["M"]][, "time"], tmp1[["F"]][, "time"], "-")))
  
  # find minimum for each woman (rowwise minimum)
  # and connect those numbers with original ID in input data.frame
  tmp3 <- tmp1[["M"]][apply(tmp2, 1, which.min), ]
  
  # ronames to represent female ID
  rownames(tmp3) <- tmp1[["F"]][, "id"]
  
  # return
  tmp3
})

# $`1`
#   id group sex time
# 2  3     1   M 11.5
#
# $`2`
#   id group sex time
# 6  5     2   M 13.2
# 7  5     2   M 13.2
# 8  5     2   M 13.2
#
# $`3`
#    id group sex time
# 12  9     3   M   18
```

Now each group has its own `data.frame()`. The `rownames()` represent the `ID` of the woman and the respective row of the man in the `data.frame()` with the smallest absolute difference in time.

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
                 group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 sex = c('M','F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F'),
                 time = c(10, 11, 11.5, 13, 13.2, 15, 9, 7.4, 18, 12, 34.5, 21))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tried with my full data.frame and I got this error : Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicated in 'row.names' are not authorized

Comment: Interesting, one possible problem could be that the `id` variable  is not a unique identifier for each woman in your `data.frame()`.

Answer (score 0):

Restructuring the data would help. Create a separate data frame for each sex, create a third data set with all unique pairings of males and females, then merge and subset to narrow it down to the desired pairs. `expand.grid` is very handy for computing these sorts of combinations, after that, `dplyr` functions can be used to handle the rest of the logic.

```
library(dplyr)

# create one data set for females
females <- df %>%
    filter(sex == "F") %>%
    select(f_id = id, f_time = time, f_group = group)

# create one data set for males
males <- df %>%
    filter(sex == "M") %>%
    select(m_id = id, m_time = time, m_group = group)

# All possible pairings of males and females
pairs <- expand.grid(f_id = females %>% pull(f_id),
                     m_id = males %>% pull(m_id),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

# Merge in information about each individual
pairs <- pairs %>%
    left_join(females, by = "f_id") %>%
    left_join(males, by = "m_id") %>%
    # eliminate any pairings that are in different groups
    filter(f_group == m_group) 

pairs
```

Result, potential pairs

```
  f_id m_id f_time f_group m_time m_group
1    2    1   11.0       1   10.0       1
2    2    3   11.0       1   11.5       1
3    2    4   11.0       1   13.0       1
4    6    5   15.0       2   13.2       2
5    7    5    9.0       2   13.2       2
6    8    5    7.4       2   13.2       2
7   12    9   21.0       3   18.0       3
8   12   10   21.0       3   12.0       3
9   12   11   21.0       3   34.5       3


# compute distances and 
# subset for the closest male to each female
pairs %>% 
    mutate(diff = abs(m_time - f_time)) %>%
    
    group_by(f_id) %>%
    filter(diff == min(diff)) %>%
    select(m_id, f_id)
```

Output, the closest pairs

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   f_id [5]
   m_id  f_id
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     2
2     5     6
3     5     7
4     5     8
5     9    12
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I like this way of doing it, very handy.